# Checking for external compass in mission planner

Tags: quadcopter, uav, ardupilot

How can I check whether the external compass is really selected for my APM 2.8 using mission planner.
The primary purpose of using the external compass is to have less electro magnetic interference and hence higher accuracy but I am really not sure which of the two is really providing the input to the system.

Comment: The Ardupilot Mega (APM) is a small computer to control drones. It's possible to combine it with GPS compass and other sensors. Ezequiel, Carlos Alphonso F., et al. "UAV aerial imaging applications for post-disaster assessment, environmental management and infrastructure development." 2014 International Conference on Unmanned Aircraft Systems (ICUAS). IEEE, 2014.

Comment: For future reference @ManuelRodriguez, comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. Partial answers, or answers you aren't confident about should still be posted as answers, since they can be improved by future edits even if the question is closed. Comments should be considered ephemeral, any comment which no longer actively helps to improve a question or answer may be deleted at any time to *tidy up* a post.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics A. Sinha, I think it's clear what you're asking, but could you explain a little about why? Understanding the background to your question might help someone to answer it. For instance, if you have both internal & external compass, they return different values after calibration, and your UAV is moving in the wrong direction, that might suggest the wrong compass is being used, but it might suggest other problems too. You may also want to look at [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) and edit your question to add more information.

Comment: @Mark thank you. I have updated my question.